# AS3. XML created from PHP needs to be send to Action Script 3

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, actionscript-3

I need to make TOP 10 players table in flash. When I click button "TOP 10" it must get data from database and print list on the game screen. 
What I want to make here is vision:

[image: my app]

I have dynamically created XML from PHP and data must be sent to Action Script 3.

Here is top.php file

```
<?php 
    $time = $_POST['time'];     
    session_start();
    $name = $_SESSION['vardas']; 
    $time = strtotime($time);
    $times = date('s:H:i', $time);
    $_SESSION['test'] = $times;
    $_SESSION['test1'] = $username;


    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_db","pass","my_db");

    $query = "SELECT userName,time FROM eurokos ORDER by time ASC LIMIT 10";
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
} else {
//    printf(" ", $mysqli->character_set_name());
}
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    echo '<results>';
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo '<user name="'.$row["userName"].'" time="'.$row["time"].'" />';
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    echo '</results>';
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <results>
    <user name="someone" time="xxx" />
    <user name="someone" time="xxx" />
    [...]
</results>
```

And here is my Action Script code:

```
 var myXml:XML;

    function uploadTops():void
    {
        var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        myLoader.load(new URLRequest("top.php"));
        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
    }
    function processXML(e:Event):void {
    myXml = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXml);
    }
    function myButton(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        uploadTops();
    //  _message = myXml.user.*; //these lines are wrong, I donn't know how to print answer
    //  message_txt.text = _message;
    }
```

I got error:

```
Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed. when trying to trace

at MemoryGame/processXML()[C:\Users\Petras\Downloads\geraseaa\geraseaa\gerase\MemoryGame.as:570]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open your XML file with a browser and then see its source , this way you will know what exactly wrong with your XML file.
It's possible that if you will add in your php file this line :

```
 header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

before this line:

```
 echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
```

it will help

Comment: Thank you, now It is shown normally here padekime.eu/top.php but now I need to show it in my flash game. Here http://www.facebook.com/JuokoEra/app_156187751211405 when I click "Top players" is nothing shown. Something is wrong with my action script code.

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė i see `This webpage is not available` at facebook page

Comment: what do you mean? Maybe that because you need to disable secure browsing in facebook, but never mind. Idea is that what I need to make that after i click button on screen appears top players list, but I don't know how to make this in action script, because trace is only console output as i know

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29772/discussion-between-cherniv-and-rimant-baltiejt)